# How to remove List iteration without ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java

My `allWordsList` is something like: `[aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, eee]`

How make a copy (`tempWordsList`) of `allWordsList` in

```
for (String aWord : aWordsList)
```

without the iteration item ( i.e. to achieve `[bbb, ccc, ddd, eee]`, then `[aaa, ccc, ddd, eee]`, etc...)?

```
public class Anagrams {

    List<String> allWordsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<List<String>> myList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    List<String> tempWordsList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public Anagrams(String allWords) {
        getWordsList(allWordsList, allWords); // getting List to copy here
        getAnagramWordsList(allWordsList);
    }

    private void getAnagramWordsList(List<String> aWordsList) {
        for (String aWord : aWordsList){
            //tempWordsList.clear();
            tempWordsList = aWordsList;
            for (Iterator<String> iterator = tempWordsList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                String string = iterator.next();
                if (string == aWord) {
                    // Remove the current element from the iterator and the list.
                    iterator.remove();
                }
            }
            myList.add(tempWordsList);
            System.out.println(aWordsList);
            System.out.println(tempWordsList); //before error both lists are without first item...
        }
    }

}
```

I went through a couple of similar cases but still don't understand it well.

Comment: You can change your `iterator` loop to a `for` loop. So you can remove the index that equals the "aWord"

Comment: You should use .equals() for string, not ==

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest problem in your code is that `tempWordsList` and `aWordsList` refer to the same object. Any change that you make to `tempWordsList` happens to `aWordsList` at the same exact time:

```
tempWordsList = aWordsList;
```

Therefore, `myList` will have multiple copies of the last modification of `aWordList`:

```
myList.add(tempWordsList);
```

adds the same object to `myList` at each iteration of the loop.

In order to make `aWordsList` and `tempWordsList` you need to replace the assignment with a copy, like this:

```
tempWordsList = new List<String>(aWordsList);
```

Comment: SOLVED! you are absolutely right, ... tempWordsList = new List<String>(aWordsList);

Answer (score 1):

> It should be like this :

```
Iterator<String> it = tempWordsList.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
    String value = it.next();
   // System.out.println("List Value:"+value);
   if (value.equals(aWord)) {
      it.remove();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The method that will solve your problem is the following, but it is not a good solve.

// Solve

```
private void getAnagramWordsList(List<String> aWordsList) {

    List<Integer> toRemove = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (String aWord : aWordsList){
        //tempWordsList.clear();
        tempWordsList = aWordsList;

        for (int i = tempWordsList.size()-1; i > 0; i--) {
            if (string.equals(tempWordsList.get(i)) {
                toRemove.add(i);
            }
        }
        for(int idx = 0; idx < toRemove.size(); idx++)
          tempWordsList.remove(idx);

        myList.add(tempWordsList);

        System.out.println(aWordsList);
        System.out.println(tempWordsList); //before error both lists are without first item...
    }
```